# How to send automated emails in wordpress (Woocommerce) after auction ends to the winning bidder?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, automation, hook-woocommerce

I have installed and running Ultimate Woocommerce Aution in my wordpress website. I want to send a specific mail with an attachment to the winning bidder's email address registered as a user in my wordpress site as soon as the auction ends . How can I do that ? Is there a way to do it Cause I don't want to send mails one by one Cause I'll be handling a lot of auctions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with this plugin. but from their [support tab](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-woocommerce-auction/#what%20hooks%20are%20available%20for%20this%20plugin), it seems you can hook to when the auction is closing: 
I just assume that `$auction_id` is the closed order ID. so maybe this code will work:

```
add_action( 'ultimate_woocommerce_auction_close', 'closing_auction_process', 50 );
function closing_auction_process($auction_id) {

   $order = new WC_Order($auction_id);
   $winner_email = $order->get_billing_email();
   wp_mail($winner_email, 'myemail@auctionsite.com', 'You won!', 'CONTENT HERE');

}
```